# Distance between inputs in a responsive form

Tags: html, css, forms

I need a pixel perfect form . Can I make?:
- the distance between the small inputs exactly 5px?
- maintain the distance to the left and right 0
- maintain the distance above 5px
- maintain the form responsive

As you can see in the example I cannot reach the first condition.

```css
form {
 position: relative;
 margin: 40px auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 85%; max-width: 350px;
} 
input {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 7px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 font-size: 14px;
 outline: none;
 color: #bbb;
 border: 0;
 background-color: whiteSmoke;
} 
#mes-any {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 49%;
 float: left;
}
#cvc {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 49%;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action='externs/select-insert.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' id='card' name='card' value=''>
 <input type='text' id='mes-any'name='mes-any' value=''>
 <input type='text' id='cvc'name= 'cvc' value=''>
</form>
```

Comment: Calc() will help you. use width:calc(50% - 2.5px); in other two input classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using **calc()** to get the width:

```css
form {
 position: relative;
 margin: 40px auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 85%; max-width: 350px;
} 
input {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 7px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 font-size: 14px;
 outline: none;
 color: #bbb;
 border: 0;
 background-color: whiteSmoke;
} 
#mes-any {
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(50% - 2.5px);
 float: left;
}
#cvc {
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(50% - 2.5px);
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action='externs/select-insert.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' id='card' name='card' value=''>
 <input type='text' id='mes-any'name='mes-any' value=''>
 <input type='text' id='cvc'name= 'cvc' value=''>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems that you win for 2 minutes!. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that using css `calc(50% - 2.5px)`

```css
form {
 position: relative;
 margin: 40px auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 85%; max-width: 350px;
} 
input {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 7px 15px; margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
 font-size: 14px;
 outline: none;
 color: #bbb;
 border: 0;
 background-color: whiteSmoke;
} 
#mes-any {
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(50% - 2.5px);
 float: left;
}
#cvc {
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(50% - 2.5px);
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action='externs/select-insert.php' method='post'>
 <input type='text' id='card' name='card' value=''>
 <input type='text' id='mes-any'name='mes-any' value=''>
 <input type='text' id='cvc'name= 'cvc' value=''>
</form>
```